# How to calculate height of UILabel if we set different types NSFontAttributeName in UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have face problem when set different type of font and color in one UILable using Attribute.My problem is how to get exact height of lable so i have provided that height to cell height and maintain my UI and text not cutting.

I have try out following things:
CODE:

```
     int italicHeight = [AppSingletonObj get_LblHeight:strJoin withWidth:270  withFont:_SETITALICFONT(14.0)];

    int normalTextHeight = [AppSingletonObj get_LblHeight:strCmt withWidth:270  withFont:_SETREGULARFONT(14.0)];

    int cellheight = italicHeight+normalTextHeight;
```

When i set frame to UILabel at that time i have used below code

================================================================

```
  int heightlbl = [AppSingletonObj get_LblHeight:strJoinTime withWidth:lblnotifyDesWidthAnswerQues withFont:_SETREGULARFONT(14.0)];
```

=======================================================

if i will calculated different height and set that height to label then height is greater and text is not fit to vertically center.

========================================================

```
    - (CGFloat)get_LblHeight:(NSString*)str withWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont *)uiFont  {

        @try
        {
            // Get text
            CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
            CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) str );
            CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength((CFStringRef) attrString);

            // Change font
            CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
            CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, stringLength), kCTFontAttributeName, ctFont);

            // Calc the size
            CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
            CFRange fitRange;
            CGSize frameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);

            CFRelease(ctFont);
            CFRelease(framesetter);
            CFRelease(attrString);

            return frameSize.height +05;
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception heightEmoji = %@",[exception description]);
        }
    }
```

=====================================================

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give your label the text and then calculate the frame and assign that frame to the label.

```
CGRect labelSize = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:size]} context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

[UILabel height calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908453/uilabel-height-calculation/33908477#33908477)

It's on swift but i think you can convert it into objective-c